# Php redirct and post confusion

Tags: javascript, php, html

I currently have a php file that redirects to another page, and the other page submits a hard-coded POST request to another website (xxxx://siteb.com/upload.php) My initial/landing page (xxxx://sitea.com/index.php) will redirect to (xxxx://sitea.com/complete.php) and loads all the data.

When I press the submit button to send the POST request to (xxx://siteb.com/upload.php) fiddler shows that the POST request originates from (xxxx://sitea.com/index.php) instead of (xxxx://siteb.com/upload.php)

The actual link in my address bar does update, but the post request still shows (xxxx://sitea.com/index.php)

I'm using javascript to handle the redirect.

```
die('<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="' . $ranFileName .'";</script>');
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you told the script to die before it could complete the post request.

instead, set action as the page you want the form to post to. it will automatically redirect the browser to that page on submit

Answer (score 0):

use a HTTP header redirect instead of javascript redirect:

```
<?php
header('Location: '.$ranFileName);
die;
```